# Set all columns of a particular row from another table in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables with same data structure. One table is updated from `server` and the other one is updated `locally`. For Instance,if the `server_table` updated first I want to update the values of a particular row in `local_table`. What would be the sqlite statement for that?
I searched for that but got the Insert statements. What would be the statement for Update? Will this effect my primary key `"_id"`. Since I am using this to populate `listviews`

Regards ,
Parvaz Bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create unique key on you field and then on updates just make use for `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` statement. You need to have a unique index on at least one column.

INSERT will insert record if does not exist and REPLACE will update if one exists.

[Please refer this link also.](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Comment: could you give me an example? like..INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_local 
    (_id,taskid,date_creation)/*can i use * here instead? and should i also select _id this is my primary auto increment key*/
 VALUES 
    (?? //how to fetch all column values from tbl_server??)

Comment: I had removed pk and auto-increment and just kept unique key on _id. That worked for me. And the statement you have written is correct one.

Comment: I need the values form my server tbl should I use cursor for fetching all the values?

Comment: Yes you can iterate using cursor for your server values

Comment: If I remove primary key and auto-increment won't it effect my listview since in android the adapters always require an "_id" as primarykey with autoinc. ??

Comment: I guess it is not necessary to have PK and AutoInc for listView adapter.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me to go with INSERT OR REPLACE INTO, I used another column as unique key.